# PHP GD affine transform picture and merge it with background

Tags: php, image-processing, matrix, gd, affinetransform

Currently developing a web picture editor, I'm allowing users to create drawings with JavaScript, and I need to export the result in PHP. I use PHP-GD to generate results.

For now, I'm working on affine transforms. Users have a workspace with given dimensions. In iOS, Android and JavaScript, they can import a picture and move it, scale it and rotate it anywhere in the workspace, and the position is saved as a transformation matrix. Now, the PHP needs to use this affine transformation matrix to position every element at the right place and export a single merged image.

I've looked into Imagick for affine transforms, but as the documentation isn't complete, and I didn't get any results with it, I'm using GD, and I'm almost reaching my goal.

Right now, I'm sure I'm not using the affine transform correctly, that's where I need your help.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
$source = imagecreatefrompng($image_path_server);
$background = imagescale($source, 500);
$arrow = imagecreatefrompng($arrow_path);
$affine = array(0.08470355177709013, 0.7807062203430081, -0.7807062203430081, 0.08470355177709013, 42.99999999999994, 199.00000000000006);
$arrow = imageaffine($arrow, $affine);
imagecopy($background, $arrow, 42.99999999999994, 199.00000000000006, 0, 0, imagesx($arrow), imagesy($arrow));
```

With this code, the arrow is well rotated and scaled, but the position is not right, and that's probably because the picture is re-framed after the affine transform.

Ideally, I'd like to avoid using imagecopy to position the image, as the position is defined in the matrix, but I didn't find how to apply the matrix on the arrow based on the background.

[image: Expected behaviour]

To be more precise, I'd like to add my arrow on the top left corner of the picture as a layer, and then apply the transform matrix so it will be positioned properly on the background. When I only apply a translation ([1,0,0,1,200,250]), it doesn't affect the position on the background, and that's exactly what I'd need here.

Anyone experienced with this kind of operations to direct me in the right direction?

Comment: where is `$arrow` resource loading? shouldn't there be `$arrow = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_arrow_image)` ?

Comment: Edited my question to add `$arrow` resource load.

Comment: It is right, the image is reframed.

As of ", but I didn't find how to apply the matrix on the arrow based on the background." Not sure what you mean :)